# Installing ubuntu 16.04 on HDD with OEM windows 10 on SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Hi I am trying to install Ubuntu on my new laptop, MSI GP62 6QF. It has Windows 10 installed on the 128 GB SSD. Now I want to install Ubuntu on the 1TB HDD. I booted into Ubuntu Live CD using a USB drive. I have choosen the following partitions for installation(I haven't made any change to SSD's partitions).

**128 GB SSD Partitions:**

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sd1 efi ------------ Windows Boot Manager
/dev/sd2      
/dev/sd3 ntfs 126GB
/dev/sd4 ntfs 1GB
```

**1TB HDD Partitions:**

```
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdb1 ntfs   300GB
/dev/sdb2 ntfs   300GB
/dev/sdb4 swap   4096 MB
/dev/sdb5 ext4 / 300GB
/dev/sdb3 ntfs   17GB (system recovery)
```

/dev/sdb4 and /dev/sdb5 partitions were created by me.

What I am confused about is what option should I select in "Device for boot Loader installation"?
**/dev/sda or /dev/sdb**

Comment: `sda` is where the EFI partition resides. You should boot Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: actually live cd automatically boot into the EFI mode. i didn't had to do anything

Answer (score 0):

The bootloader for your Windows is on SSD. While installing Ubuntu, you should select HDD for bootloader I think. This way, your windows bootloader will not get affected and you will be able to boot into any OS just be selecting the boot drive at boot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I did tried that earlier but with no luck.. I had finally given up on installing ubuntu on this pc.